# QGIS can't detect negative values?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, rule-based

I'm working with the last version of QGIS (3.8.3-Zanzibar), and I'm trying to represent a Rule-Based Symbology from a CSV file with the following rules:

[image: Figure 1]

And the data from the prcptot column is this:

[image: Figure 2]

As you can see, all the prcptot values are negative (smaller than 0), but the output that QGIS is giving to me is the next:

[image: Figure 3]

All the red triangles should be inverted blue triangles... I think that QGIS is taking all the values as positive numbers, but I don't know why or what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rules seem not to be correct.
The first rule of your example is:

```
"prcptot" = "prcptot" > 0 AND "p.prcptot" <=0.09
```

while I guess it should read:

```
"prcptot" > 0 AND "p.prcptot" <=0.09
```

Stating `"prcptot" = "prcptot"`is a tautology, i.e. it gets always evaluated as `true`.
The fact that it is chained with a `> 0` before the `AND` operator might confuse the parser, and that could be the reason why not all triangles are red.

So the full rule set would be:

```
"prcptot" > 0 AND "p.prcptot" <=0.09
"prcptot" > 0 AND "p.prcptot" > 0.09
"prcptot" < 0 AND "p.prcptot" <= 0.09
"prcptot" < 0 AND "p.prcptot" > 0.09
"prcptot" = 0 OR "p.prcptot" IS NULL
```

Comment: I think the last one should be `IS NULL`

Comment: Thank you both! It worked perfectly!

Comment: @MrXsquared thanks: edited

Comment: @DobriDobrev feel free to [accept](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if it solved your question